# Bootstrap 3.0: Keeping Panel fixed on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Bootstrap's Panel to show error messages, just below the navbar. Want them scroll with page so that user's can have error messages with them.

```
#errorDiv {
  position:fixed;
}
```

Doesn't work for me. Check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/aGnxz/7/). In my case panels just disappears from the page.

Comment: Seems to work fine. Under what circumstances does it "disappear"? http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/aGnxz/9

Comment: I agree, works fine in the fiddle.  You're giving position fixed, without any top/bottom/left/right positioning.  Could assigning those help?

Comment: Ok. How can I keep the size intact? Adding `top:0;` also didn't help.